# Complex Number Cube Roots Problem

Tags: complex-numbers

There exists a complex number of the form $z = x + yi,$ where $x$ and $y$ are positive integers, such that
$$z^3 = -74 + ci,$$for some integer $c.$ Find $z.$

I tried to simplify $\sqrt[3]{-74 + ci}$ but then didn't really see where I could go from there.

Comment: Have you tried solving $x^3-3xy^2=-74,\,3x^2y-y^3=c$? You may also find polar form helpful.

Comment: I put it in polar form and solved it... Thanks!

Comment: @NoahD. In that case you can self answer the question instead of deleting

Comment: Please, add your solution in the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your equation is equivalent to the two equations $x^3-3xy^2 = -74$ and $3x^2y - y^3 = c$.

Now the point is that $x,y$ have to be positive integers. The cubic equation equation $x^3 -3y^2 x + 74 = 0$ has integer coefficients, thus each positive integer solution $x$ must satisfy condition

(1) $x$ is a divisor of $74$.

Thus the only candidates are $x_1 = 1, x_2 = 2, x_3 = 37, x_4 = 74$. This yields quadratric equations $-3x_i y^2 + x_i^3 + 74 = 0$ for $y$. Solutions are $y = \pm \sqrt{\dfrac{x_i^3+74}{3x_i}}$. This gives the condition

(2) $y(x_i)  = \sqrt{\dfrac{x_i^3+74}{3x_i}}$ is an integer.

We have $y(x_1) = \sqrt{25} = 5$, $y(x_2) = \sqrt{41/3}$, $y(x_3) = \sqrt{457}$ and $y(x_4) = \sqrt{5477/3}$. Among these, the only integer is $y(x_1) = 5$.

Thus we must have $x=1, y= 5$ and $c = -110$.

**Remark:**

As Oscar Lanzi commented, we can use a more elegant argument to rule out some of the $x_i$. In fact, the equation $x^3-3xy^2 = -74$ implies
$$x^3 \equiv 1\bmod3$$
which is equivalent to
$$x \equiv 1\bmod3 .$$
$x = x_2, x_4$ do not satisfy this.

Comment: Technically, you should include $x=74$ as a possibility, but this then does not give an integer radicand.  Alternatively you may argue that $2$ and $74$ are both doomed since $2^3-6y^2+74\not\equiv0\bmod 3$ for all integers $y$.

Comment: Take a look at the refinements along these lines.  Feel free to roll back if you find it not useful.

Comment: @OscarLanzi Thank you for your comment, indeed I forgot $x = 74$ ;-) Although I find you $\mod 3$-argument very useful, I rolled back, but added a remark.